# Наследование в python без аргумента

Tags: python, ооп, наследование

Реализовать класс Fruit с переменными size, weight (числовые значения) и taste (строковое), отнаследовать от него классы apple с новой переменной color (строковое значение) и orange с переменной color, но без taste. Положить два яблока и апельсин в FruitBasket.

Вопрос, если я от Fruit наследую Orange - как не наследовать с переменный taste?

Так не пропускает, пишет, что потерян 1 аргумент.

```
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, size, weight, taste):
        self.size = size
        self.weight = weight
        self._taste = taste


class Apple(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, size, weight, _taste, color):
        super().__init__(size, weight, _taste)
        self.color = color


class Orange(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, size, weight, color):
        super().__init__(size, weight)
        self.color = color


first_apple = Apple(1, 5, 'Сочное', 'Красное')
second_apple = Apple(2, 7, 'Кислое', 'Зеленое')
orange = Orange(3, 8, 'Оранжевый')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы наследуете от "фрукт". Это значит все атрибуты фрукта будут переданы в потомка ("яблоко", "апельсин").
Вижу несколько вариантов:

- образовать родительский класс без вкуса, потомка со вкусом и затем следующего потомка "яблоко"
- сделать родительский класс более гибким - например назначить вкус - параметром по умолчанию, тогда его можно указывать для "яблока" и не указывать для "апельсина"

  ```
  class Fruit:
      def __init__(self, size, weight, taste=""):
          self.size = size
          self.weight = weight
          self.taste = taste

  second_apple = Apple(2, 7, 'Кислое', 'Зеленое')
  orange = Orange(3, 8, 'Оранжевый')
  ```
- либо отказаться от переменных и сделать словарь атрибутов в главном родителе без рамок названий и пр. Затем при наследовании в нём будут храниться все параметры (код следующего примера тестировался на python 2):

  ```
  class Fruit1:
      def __init__(self, **fruit_dict):
          self.attr = fruit_dict

  class Apple1(Fruit1):
      def __init__(self, **fruit_dict):
         Fruit1.__init__(self, **fruit_dict)

  first_apple1 = Apple1(**{"size": 3, "weight": 5, "taste": 'Сочное', "color": 'Красное'})
  orange1 = Orange1(**{"size": 3, "weight": 5, "color": 'Оранжевый'})

  print(first_apple1.attr)
  print(orange1.attr)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вы не сможете выборочно передавать в подкласс *обязательные* (arbitraty) аргументы по определению. Но вы можете выборочно их забирать в подклассе, если в родительском класс оставите некоторую свободу действий.

```
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, size, weight, taste, *args, **kwargs):
        self.size = size
        self.weight = weight
        self._taste = taste


class Apple(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, size, weight, _taste, color):
        super().__init__(size, weight, _taste)
        self.color = color


class Orange(Fruit):
    def __init__(self, size, weight, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(size, weight, color)
        self.color = color


first_apple = Apple(1, 5, 'Сочное', 'Красное')
second_apple = Apple(2, 7, 'Кислое', 'Зеленое')
orange = Orange(3, 8, 'Оранжевый')
```

И тогда:

```
print(orange.weight)
print(second_apple._taste)
```

На выходе даст:

```
8
Кислое
```